# Handling combinatorial explosion when converting AoS to SoA

Tags: c++, performance

Suppose I want to convert an Array of Structures into a Structure of Arrays with a runtime-parameter indicating which of the members of the source structure should be converted. For example:

```
struct SourceElement {
  string member1;
  float member2;
  int member3;
  //More members...
};
auto source_elements = ...; //A forward-iterable range of SourceElement objects

vector<string> members1;
vector<float> members2;
vector<int> members3;

for(auto& source_element : source_elements) {
  if(member1_required) {
    members1.push_back(source_element.member1);
  }
  if(member2_required) {
    members2.push_back(source_element.member2);
  }
  if(member3_required) {
    members3.push_back(source_element.member3);
  }
  //...and so on...
}
//Some of the vectors might be empty, which I am fine with
```

I want to get rid of the conditionals within the loop in the hopes that the conditional-less code will run a bit faster. The typical way I know of is to simply move the conditionals out of the loop, which works fine if it is only a single conditional, but with multiple conditionals this results in a combinatorial explosion - for `N` members I have to write `2^N` different loop bodies. Adding a new member requires writing a lot of code as well. Here is an example of how this looks:

```
if(member1_required && !member2_required && !member3_required) {
  for(auto& source_element : source_elements) {
    members1.push_back(source_element.member1);
  }
} else if(member1_required && member2_required && !member3_required) {
  for(auto& source_element : source_elements) {
    members1.push_back(source_element.member1);
    members2.push_back(source_element.member2);
  }
}
//... and so on
```

What is a good way to deal with this sort of problem? An ideal solution should have the following properties:

- Generated code should be as close as possible to a hand-rolled solution (one for-loop per combination)
- Adding new members should require little effort
- Destructuring the source element should allow for data transformations (e.g. `members1.push_back(my_conversion(source_element.member1))`). A simple case: SourceElement has a `double` member, but I want to store only `float` data
- Source data might come from a forward iterator, so one cannot assume that all data is stored linearily in memory

Comment: I think you are mistaken. If there are `N` members you need `N` loops. If `member1` and `member2` is required, this is handled by the corresponding `if` statements for both `member1` and `member2`.

Comment: Have you *measured* a performance problem with this? This is the sort of thing that an optimising compiler will do for you. Do you even need to *copy* the data here? Can you instead write a *view* of the data in the form you want?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would prefer to not iterate over the data multiple times.

Comment: @Caleth A copy is required because the data will be processed by multiple threads. Regarding performance, I would like to measure, it was during this process that I thought about how one could write a C++-specific solution that would achieve the same goal as writing every combination myself.

Comment: Are `member1_required` et. al. runtime or compiletime values?

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ still has to obey the laws of physics of our shared universe. Either you have one loop, and have `N` if statements in the loop, or have `N` separate loops. There might be an evil template based approach that will auto-generate `2^N` if statements, with the right conditions for each one, that depends on trivial compiler optimization to optimize away dead code, but it's still going to generate `2^N` combinations. Basic laws of physics. Can't do much about them.

Comment: They are runtime values (as stated in the question)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not sure I understood your initial statement correctly. I believe I have to write `2^N` loops, however because of the if-statements being outside of the loop, only a single one of these loops gets executed at runtime (my second code example). I could do it with only `N` loops, but then it is not a single-pass algorithm anymore, i.e. multiple loops might be executed. So the question is: Is there an alternative single-pass solution in which I don't have to write `2^N` loops by hand?

Comment: Only by, potentially, using evil templates, as I mentioned. You won't write `2^N` loops by hand, but the templates will effectively expanded to the same `2^N` loops. You cannot defeat the laws of physics of our shared universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use templates, example (untested):

```
struct DestElements
{
    vector<string> members1;
    vector<float> members2;
    vector<int> members3;
};

template<uint32_t bitMask>
DestElements copy( const SourceElement* begin, const SourceElement* end )
{
    DestElements dest;
    for( ; begin < end; begin++ )
    {
        if constexpr( bitMask & 1 )
            dest.members1.push_back( begin->member1 );
        if constexpr( bitMask & 2 )
            dest.members2.push_back( begin->member2 );
        if constexpr( bitMask & 4 )
            dest.members3.push_back( begin->member3 );
    }
    return std::move( dest );
}

using pfnCopy = DestElements( *)( const SourceElement* begin, const SourceElement* end );

static const std::array<pfnCopy, 8> dispatch =
{
    // You can do crazy C++ metaprogramming here, std::apply, std::make_index_sequence, etc.
    // When I have too large count of them, I write ~2 lines of C# in a T4 template instead.
    &copy<0>, &copy<1>, &copy<2>, &copy<3>, &copy<4>, &copy<5>, &copy<6>, &copy<7>,
};

// Usage
uint32_t mask = 0;
if( member1_required ) mask |= 1;
if( member2_required ) mask |= 2;
if( member3_required ) mask |= 4;
DestElements dest = dispatch[ mask ]( source_elements.data(),
                source_elements.data() + source_elements.size() );
```

You'll need to replace the const pointer with the type of your forward iterator, obviously.

However, I’m not sure this will have measurable effect on performance. All modern CPUs do branch prediction. These conditions don’t change while you iterating. After the first loop iteration, all these branches will be predicted with 100% accuracy.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! Also thanks for pointing out branch prediction, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can select which functions to run in your loop from a map of lambdas before the loop. Like the others here have said though, this is unlikely to give a performance boost. The following code is a working example:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include<functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct component
{
    float member1;
    std::string member2;
    int member3;
};

struct vector_builder
{
    std::vector<std::function<void(component&)>> commands;

    std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void(component&)>> function_map{
    {1, [&](component& comp){members1.push_back(comp.member1);}},
    {2, [&](component& comp){members2.push_back(comp.member2);}},
    {3, [&](component& comp){members3.push_back(comp.member3);}}
    };

    vector_builder(std::vector<int> must_contain)
    {
        for(auto i : must_contain) {commands.push_back(function_map[i]);}
    }

    std::vector<float> members1;
    std::vector<std::string> members2;
    std::vector<int> members3;

    void Push(component& c) {for(auto func : commands) func(c);}
};

int main()
{
    // Create an iterable collection of component objects we want to transform
    std::vector<component> components{{2.1, "hello", 5}, 
                                      {3.4, "world", 6}, 
                                      {0.5, "great", 10}};

    // Let's say we want only members 2 and 3 to be made into vectors:
    vector_builder builder({2, 3});

    // Now the loop comprises only the two push_back functions we wanted
    for (auto& comp : components) builder.Push(comp);


    // Print the results
    std::cout << "members1: "; // This should be empty.
    for (auto& i : builder.members1) std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\nmembers2: ";
    for (auto& i : builder.members2) std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\nmembers3: ";
    for (auto& i : builder.members3) std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```